# NSSoundDelegate not being called

Tags: objective-c, audio

I am updating some legacy objective C code to be able to be compiled under OSX 10.13. The legacy code worked and most of the update code does as well except for an NSSoundDelegate that needs to handle a didFinishPlaying function. The delegate method is not being called. The delegate method is contained in a class called MyClass. Here is relevant code.

In MyClass.h:

```
@class MyClass;
@protocol MyClass <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)sound:(NSSound *)sound didFinishPlaying:(BOOL)flag;
@end

@interface MyClass : NSObject <NSSoundDelegate>
{
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <NSSoundDelegate> delegate;

- (void)sound:(NSSound *)sound didFinishPlaying:(BOOL)flag;
- (id) init;
@end
```

Then in MyClass.m:

```
@implementation MyClass

@synthesize delegate;

- (void)sound:(NSSound *)sound didFinishPlaying:(BOOL)flag
{
if (flag) {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]   postNotificationName:@"handleNSSoundDidFinishPlaying" object:sound];
}
}

- (id)init
{
    MyClass *thePointer;

    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        thePointer = self;
        self.delegate = (id)thePointer;
        isInitialized = NO;
        isClosing = NO;
        [self set_currentSounds:[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0]];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem! When allocating the sound to be played, you have to set the sounds delegate using [theSnd setDelegate:self]; so that when the sound stops playing, the delegate gets called, in this case the delegate is in the MyClass .m file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should notify the delegate object like:

```
if([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(sound: didFinishPlaying:)])
    [_delegate sound:self didFinishPlaying:_flag];
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to express an interest. I'm not sure I understand your suggestion. The NSSound delegate method (didFinishPlaying) is not getting called. Within my implementation of the delegate method, I will issue a notification to code within MyClass that the delegate method had executed and other tasks relating to the finish of the  sound playing need to be completed. However, I never get to the notification because I never get to the delegate method. I don't understand how your suggestion helps get the delegate to cook off nor where your suggestion should be placed.

Comment: I modified the init as follows:        thePointer = self;
        thePointer.delegate = (id)self;
        if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(sound: didFinishPlaying:)]) {
            isInitialized = NO;
            isClosing = NO;
            [self set_currentSounds:[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0]];
        };
and execution does reach isInitialized = NO.